# Why is the length of the word_index greater than num_words?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp

I have a code, about text preprocessing for deep learning:

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = 10000)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X)
tokenizer.word_index
```

but when I check the length of tokenizer.word_index, safe in the knowledge to get 10000, I get 13233.The length of X is equal to 11541(a dataframe column containing 11541, if it matters to know, however). So my question arises: which is vocabulary size? num_words or the length of word_index? It seems I have confused! Any helps appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [official docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer), the argument `num_words` is,

> the maximum number of words to keep, based on word frequency. Only the most common `num_words-1` words will be kept.

`word_index` will hold all the words which are present in `texts`. But the difference is observed when you use `Tokenizer.texts_to_sequences`. For instance, let us consider some sentences,

```py
texts = [
    'hello world' , 
    'hello python' , 
    'python' , 
    'hello java' ,
    'hello java' , 
    'hello python'
]
# Frequency of words, hello -> 5, python -> 3 , java -> 2 , world -> 1
tokenizer = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer( num_words=3 )
tokenizer.fit_on_texts( texts )
print( tokenizer.word_index )
```

The output of the above snippet will be,

```py
{'hello': 1, 'python': 2, 'java': 3, 'world': 4}
```

According to the docs, the top `num_words-1` words ( based on their frequency ) must only be used while transforming the words to indices. In our case `num_words=3` and hence we'd expect the Tokenizer to only use `2` words for the transformation. The two most common words in `texts` are `hello` and `python`. Consider this example to inspect the output of `texts_to_sequences`

```py
input_seq = [
    'hello' , 
    'hello java' , 
    'hello python' , 
    'hello python java'
]
print( tokenizer.texts_to_sequences( input_seq ) )
```

The output,

```py
[[1], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

Observe that in the first sentence, `hello` is encoded as expected. In the second sentence, the word `java` isn't encoded as it was not included in the vocabulary. In the third sentence, both the words `hello` and `python` are included, which is the expected behavior as per our assumption. In the fourth sentence, the word `java` isn't encoded in the output.

> So my question arises: which is vocabulary size? `num_words` or the length of `word_index`?

As you might have understood, `num_words` is the vocab size as only these many words are being encoded in the output. Rest of the words, in our case `java` and `world` are simply omitted from the transformation.

Comment: A complete answer! Thanks

Comment: Do accept the answer, if it helped you.

Comment: word_index does not include the characters included by default in the tokenizer filter parameter. From the doc:  filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n',